# How do I communicate / trigger a Webtask from Firebas?

Tags: firebase, task, webhooks

In an interesting [blogpost](https://auth0.com/blog/firebase-authentication-with-firebase-3.0-and-auth0-integration/) about 'Firebase Authentication with the Firebase 3.0 SDK and Auth0 Integration', it is stated that:

> You can even have Firebase communicate with Webtask!

Now I can imagine the **(web)client** triggering a Firebase operation and subsequently a [Webtask](https://webtask.io/), but not the other way around. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Firebase can run as a serverless app, but it can also run on the server. You can even have Firebase communicate with Webtask! *(sic!)*

I think that paragraph is misleadingly phrased, perhaps it was just added at the last minute to spark interest. You can have a webtask communicate with Firebase, not the other way around. You don't "run Firebase" on your server either.

**TL;DR:** A client application may call a webtask with an HTTP request, and that task can read/write the database, but not in any other order.

---

Here's a quick and dirty reality check as of Nov. 2016:

- The Realtime Database by itself **does not** provide you with a way of executing code. This includes responding to database changes and user requests, handling fan-in and fan-out operations, etc. There is no support for webhooks either.
- Which means you have to provide your own execution environment for such logic on a custom server, or you can try to cram as much as possible into the client code. *This is a pretty exhaustive topic by itself.*
- Webtasks are short-lived functions that respond to HTTP requests. Their lifecycle always starts with a request, so they are not fit for continuously *watching* the database for changes. But they are perfectly valid for handling requests coming in from your client application.
- As you can store "secrets" for the webtasks, you can authenticate the task on an *admin* access level. This gives you the possibility to verify client tokens – which should be sent along with the request –; perform complex authorization and validation, and perform RTDB write operations you wouldn't trust the clients with.
  Or trigger external services securely. *The possibilities are close to endless.*